# use class Media in apps

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I have some extension page and apps in my `django-cms`. I try to load some JS file in my app like this, in my `admin.py`

```
class CustomCodeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        js = ('js/connect.js', 'js/testing.js')

admin.site.register(CustomCode, CustomCodeAdmin)
```

But the I have the same configuration in my extension page and it works perfectly.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from cms.extensions import PageExtensionAdmin

from .models import IconExtension


class IconExtensionAdmin(PageExtensionAdmin):
    class Media:
        js = ('js/connect.js', 'js/testing.js')

admin.site.register(IconExtension, IconExtensionAdmin)
```

Any idea why it works in one and not in the others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To include TinyMCE in your app, [download](https://www.tinymce.com/download/) the library, and include tinymce folder inside static folder of your project.

After that, inside static/js create a JS file to put the configuration of your tinyMCE in my case `tinymce_config.js`

In your app inside cms_plugin.py include this

```
  class Media:
    js = ('tinymce/tinymce.min.js', 'js/tinymce_config.js')
```

my tinymce_config.js is like this

```
// TinyMCE 4 configuration
// Modify the following code to customize TinyMCE

tinymce.init({
  selector: "textarea",
  // Only required plugins are included. However, you can add more as per your needs.
  // Spellchecker plugin is excluded as it produces an error in version 4.x
  plugins: [
      "advlist autolink link image lists charmap preview hr",
      "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media",
      "table contextmenu emoticons textcolor"
  ],

  // Customize the toolbars below. You can also add new ones.
  toolbar1: "bold italic underline | blockquote | bullist numlist| hr | formatselect fontselect fontsizeselect",
  toolbar2: "undo redo | forecolor backcolor | link unlink | image media | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | outdent indent | searchreplace |code",
  // toolbar3: " add buttons here ",

  // Aditional options. Customize them as per your needs.
  height: 350,
  resize: "both",
  image_advtab: true,
  toolbar_items_size: "medium",
  menubar: true,

  // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS) for better typography
  content_css : "/static/css/style.css"
  // If your stylesheet is inside `static/css/` directory, just replace
  // `style.css` with your stylesheet's name. You don't need to change the path.
});
```

I use this [link](https://github.com/bhch/django-tinymce-noapp) like references